# Error after analyzing adding C# custom rule on SonarQube

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I developed a custom rule for C# using Roslyn in VS2015, I deployed it under SonarQube 6.4 and activated it in my quality profile.

Then, I analyzed several .cs files under the same directory using sonar-scanner. But I got this error

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Custom and 3rd party Roslyn analyzers are only by MSBuild 14. Either use MSBuild 14, or disable the custom/3rd party Roslyn analyzers in your quality profile.
    at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.analyze(CSharpSensor.java:141)
    at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.executeInternal(CSharpSensor.java:112)
    at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.execute(CSharpSensor.java:79)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:57)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:49)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:74)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:175)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:143)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:128)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:262)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:257)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:247)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:143)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:128)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:143)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:128)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:118)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:117)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
```

Once the rule deactivated, I can analyze my .cs files normally

I cannot use [SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild), because it requires a whole project to analyze, but in my case, **I can only have a directory of .cs files**, this is why I need to use sonar-scanner

I saw [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/TeamCity.SonarQubePlugin/issues/35) that a solution has been developed, but is it available currently?

Is there a solution I can analyze my files with my new rule under sonar-scanner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [Scanner for MSBuild](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) is a requirement for any analysis of .Net code with SonarQube. For reasons you've already made clear in fact:

- C# rules (e.g. from SonarC#) rely on the Roslyn framework
- Roslyn is a Microsoft framework, which kicks in during compilation of the code
- Roslyn-based analyzers therefore require *msbuild* execution
- SonarQube analysis of .Net code therefore requires to use the [Scanner for MSBuild](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) (which integrates with *msbuild*)

For all above reasons, it is not possible to analyze individual .cs files with any other scanner.